# Autocomplete function an initial line when loading the page

Tags: html, css

When I first load my index.html page, there's a gray line, I assume it has to do with the added border to do.

```css
/* Styles for the autocomplete dropdown */
.autocomplete-items {
    position: relative;
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    list-style-type: none; /* Remove the list icon */
    width: 200px; /* Match the width of the input field */
    border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Add a border */
    border-radius: 5px; /* Add some border radius for a rounded appearance */
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); /* Add a subtle box shadow for depth */
    background-color: #fff; /* Set a background color */
}

/* Styles for each autocomplete item */
.autocomplete-item {
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Highlight the selected item */
.autocomplete-item:hover {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

/* Highlight the selected item */
.autocomplete-item.active {
    background-color: #ccc; /* Customize the highlight color */
}

/* Styles for the input field */
input[type="text"] {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid transparent; /* Set initial border to transparent */
    transition: border 0.3s; /* Add a transition for a smooth effect */
    margin: 0; /* Reset margin to zero */
    padding: 0; /* Reset padding to zero */
}

/* Add border only when the input is focused (clicked) */
input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="text"]:not(:placeholder-shown) {
    border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Show border when focused (clicked) or not empty */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Story Fetcher</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/autocomplete.css"> <!-- Include the new CSS file for autocomplete -->
    <script type="module" src="autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script src="country.js"></script> <!-- Include your country.js script here -->
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Select a country</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div id="content-wrapper">
            <div id="get-container">
                <input type="text" id="country-name" placeholder="Enter a country" autocomplete="off">
                <div id="suggestion-list" class="autocomplete-items"></div>
                
                <div id="error-message"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="story-container">
                <div id="generated-text"></div>
                <button id="clear">Clear</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I remove the line that's initially appearing? This is the last thing I have to do for the design before I start adding in more content.

Comment: Can you attach the output page?

Comment: Here's an image https://imageupload.io/n2duxqIIfpqNU2Y

Comment: I converted the code to a snippet for people to examine the result. From what I see your `<div id="suggestion-list" class="autocomplete-items"></div>` still has a border when it is empty, it looks like a line of 2px but it's actually the 1px border of the empty div. You probably want to hide it by default and show it only when a country is selected with JavaScript, but without the relevant Js code it will be hard to tell you exactly how

Comment: This line causes in `. autocomplete-items` style: `border: 1px solid #ccc;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line is caused by the `border` attribute on the `autocomplete-items`.

You could apply that `border` styling only if the [element isn't empty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) so the line will only appear if the `<div>` has a child element.

So when your `autocomplete.js` script adds an element in the `autocomplete-list`, the CSS rule below will aply and the border will be shown.

```css
.autocomplete-items:not(:empty) {
   border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Add a border */
}
```

---

```css
/* Styles for the autocomplete dropdown */
.autocomplete-items {
    position: relative;
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    list-style-type: none; /* Remove the list icon */
    width: 200px; /* Match the width of the input field */
   
    border-radius: 5px; /* Add some border radius for a rounded appearance */
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); /* Add a subtle box shadow for depth */
    background-color: #fff; /* Set a background color */
}

.autocomplete-items:not(:empty) {
   border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Add a border */
 }

/* Styles for each autocomplete item */
.autocomplete-item {
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Highlight the selected item */
.autocomplete-item:hover {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

/* Highlight the selected item */
.autocomplete-item.active {
    background-color: #ccc; /* Customize the highlight color */
}

/* Styles for the input field */
input[type="text"] {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid transparent; /* Set initial border to transparent */
    transition: border 0.3s; /* Add a transition for a smooth effect */
    margin: 0; /* Reset margin to zero */
    padding: 0; /* Reset padding to zero */
}

/* Add border only when the input is focused (clicked) */
input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="text"]:not(:placeholder-shown) {
    border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Show border when focused (clicked) or not empty */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Story Fetcher</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/autocomplete.css"> <!-- Include the new CSS file for autocomplete -->
    <script type="module" src="autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script src="country.js"></script> <!-- Include your country.js script here -->
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Select a country</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div id="content-wrapper">
            <div id="get-container">
                <input type="text" id="country-name" placeholder="Enter a country" autocomplete="off">
                <div id="suggestion-list" class="autocomplete-items"></div>
                
                <div id="error-message"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="story-container">
                <div id="generated-text"></div>
                <button id="clear">Clear</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```